# C# events initialisation

Tags: c#, .net, events

Consider the "application" where an object (Thrower) is throwing a ball to another object (Receiver). The event (BallIsThrowed) happens when the ball is thrown.

Here are the 2 classes :
[image]

then the entry point :

[image]

And finally the methods pointed by the delegate when events are fired :
[image]

This is working well.

Now I want to comment this line :

[image]

because I want to say that the ball was not thrown.

The result is a null Exception :

[image]

This is normal because at this point BallIsThrowed is null

To solve this, I initilise my event :
[image]

But then my problem is that my code is never taking the event when I decomment "receiver.Register(thrower)"

My questions are :
How can I have the 2 method EventMethod fired ?

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of posting it as an image.

Comment: if (BallIsThrowed != null) BallIsThrowed(this, EventArgs.Empty);

Comment: `BallIsThrown` (past participle).

Comment: Ian P, thank you, it was indeed so trivial...

Comment: Savana, I have tried with the code sample method (ctrl + k), but I always have the problem that only a part of my code is correctly formated

Comment: -1 for posting screenshots of your code. Seriously, don't do that.

Comment: Kendall, I know and it took me much more time to write the question... too bad. Still don't understand how to format correctly the C# code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear with me: you are setting an event handler to BallIsThrowed, then you use IthrowTheBall() to actually trigger the event, with this code:

```
BallIsThrowed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

When you try to call an event handler, in this case the BallIsThrowed, it must exists or it will throw a NullReferenceException. So, in order for this to work, it must exists an event handler BallIsThrowed. It actually does, until you comment this line:

```
//BallIsThrowed += new EventHandler(method.EventMethod2);
```

So basically you need to verify if the EventHandler exists before firing it:

> if (BallIsThrowed != null)
>       BallIsThrowed(this, EventArgs.Empty);

Answer (score 4):

The best practice way to fire an event looks like this:

```
EventHandler ballIsThrowed = BallIsThrowed;
if (ballIsThrowed != null)
{
    ballIsThrowed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

The reason for the temporary variable is to prevent race conditions between the null check and the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Another (more elegant, if you ask me) way of doing this is:

```
(BallIsThrowed??delegate{})(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Compact, thread safe...

Answer (score 0):

Two things that need to be corrected:

1. In your Event Invoker, check `EventHandler != null` because you dont know if anyone registered to your handler.

   ```
   var ballThrown = BallIsThrowed;
   if (ballThrown != null)
   {
      ballThrown(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
   ```
2. For general knowledge, In order to register more then one `delegate` to your
   `EventHandler`, dont register it via the `=` operator, but via the
   `+=` operator, meaning you want to append a new `delegate`:

   ```
   public void IThrowTheBall()
   {
       // Do stuff

       // You dont have to register this delegate, you can append it to the current 
       // delegates already registered
       BallIsThrowed += method.EventMethod1;
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks this is the second answer to my questions => to use the += operator

Comment: You asked two questions, i gave two answers :)